# Backlog linked WIT visibility

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

All added links[All displayed links in backlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o8Sx.jpg)

We are working with a solution based portfolio. One solution project covers requirements for multiple other projects. I created links as can be seen in the attached images from multiple projects, these are all parent child links. When I go back to the backlog view I will only see the one project available and the others are not displayed. Does this have to do with security settings? I can't find the reason why one project is displayed and the others are not.

Answer (score 0):

The work items which show up (visibility) on your team's backlog are managed by `area` and `iteration`.

The selected area paths will determine what shows up on your team's backlog and what work items your team is responsible for.

The iterations selected will appear in the Backlogs hub for your team. Each iteration will have a backlog and board to help your team plan and manage work.

Please see [About area and iteration paths (aka sprints)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts) and [Define area paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for details.